# How to navigate website with back button while using HTML History API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

I am currently using the following JS code to create a navigation menu on the side.

```
$(".side-item-link").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');

    $.ajax({
        url : '/' + id + '/only/',
        type : 'GET',

        success : function(data){
            var response = $(data);

            $("#content").html(response.filter("#product-block"));
            $(".breadcrumb").html(response.filter(".breadcrumbs"));
            $("#search").val('');
        }
    });

    history.pushState(null, null, '../' + id);
});
```

I can browse perfectly by clicking the buttons and the `history.pushState` changes the URL accordingly. However, I cannot navigate backwards by using the back button. If I press the button the previous data are not loaded. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

When you call pushState, the first argument is a *state object*.

*From MDN:*

> ```
> var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
> history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
> ```

You should pass in an object that contains the state of the page instead of `null`.

Then, [listen for a popstate event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate):

```
addEventListener("popstate", function (event) {
    console.log(event.state);
})
```

The event firing will tell you that the user has navigated through the history. The value of `event.state` will contain the data you added with `pushState` for the page they are going to. You can use that to restore the DOM to that state.

Comment: Right now I'm not using the first variable but I'm updating the content by passing variable to my template via views. I'm using Django backend. Do I have to use `JsonResponse` to pass json array and then use that to create the content?

Comment: No, you don't need to use JSON. (Although if you're sending back large chunks of HTML then I'd start to wonder if there's any point in using Ajax in the first place).

Comment: But I can see in your example code that `stateObj` is a JSON array. I'm really confused. Sorry, I'm a newbie to JS.

Comment: No, in the example it is a JavaScript object. There's [no JSON](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) anywhere near it. You can stick more-or-less any kind of data there.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

```
$(window).on('popstate',function(){
     alert(window.location.href);
});
```

Personally your code in your case should be something like this

```
var AppendData = function(id){
     $.ajax({
        url : '/' + id + '/only/',
        type : 'GET',

        success : function(data){
            var response = $(data);

            $("#content").html(response.filter("#product-block"));
            $(".breadcrumb").html(response.filter(".breadcrumbs"));
            $("#search").val('');
        }
    });
}

$(".side-item-link").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');

    //run function here 
    AppendData(id);
    history.pushState(null, null, '../' + id);
});
$(window).on('popstate',function(){
     //get id from url
     // split url to get last string  in your case its Id
     var split_url = (window.location.href).split('/');
     var id = split_url[split_url.length-1];
     //check if this id element is found or not
     if($('#'+ id).length > 0){
         //$('#' + id).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
         //$('#' + id).parent().addClass('active');
         AppendData(id);
     }
});
```

Comment: How will I decide whether the user is going back or forward with the popstate function?

Comment: @MiniGunnR why you want to know he goback or forward? I think you just want to get the id from url and run your ajax depended on it .. right?